# How to remove from LINQ results, matching elements from array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have LINQ result, and I have List.
I want to do Where() on the LINQ and to REMOVE all the matching strings from the List.

I get errors of:
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

What can I do?

Comment: please post a full code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` before your `Where` call to force LINQ-to-SQL to download all results to the client and perform a local `Where`.

(Since your `Where` call cannot be performed on the server, you need to do it on the client)

Comment: Does AsEnumerable always force materialisation?

Comment: Because it's effectively just a cast: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx "The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T> itself."

Comment: @Rob: But it prevents you from calling `IQueryable` methods.  Calling `Enumerable` LINQ methods will force materialization.

Comment: Compare `List<int> ints = new List<int>{1,2,3,4}; var evens = ints.Where(x => x%2==0).AsEnumerable(); foreach(int i in evens){ ints.Remove(i); }` with `List<int> ints = new List<int> 1,2,3,4}; var evens = ints.Where(x => x%2==0).ToList(); foreach(int i in evens){ ints.Remove(i); }` (Sorry about the formatting)

Comment: @Rob: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @Slaks sorry, thought we were dealing with linq to objects. +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy (with ToList, which is faster than ToArray) of the items you're removing:

```
var removeMe = list.Where(...).ToList();
```

Now removeMe wil be safe to iterate through, however, a better approach would be to use the [List.RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method, because then you don't need any temporary data structures

Comment: Unless your set has exactly 2^N items, `ToArray` will need to copy to a smaller array after it finishes (since the array must be exactly the right size).  Since lists can have extra space at the end, `ToList` will involve fewer copies.

Comment: `.Where().ToList()` will be faster than `.ToList().RemoveAll()`, since it won't need to shift the items in the list.